# How can I best decouple two classes, which one way dependencies

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, decoupling

I am attempting to create a D&D combat encounter simulator using C++ and since it's D&D, all aspects of the simulation are going to depend heavily on the "Dice" Class and its methods.
I could instantiate a "Dice" object every time another class needs
to invoke its methods, however, that would leave everything heavily
coupled and make it very difficult to make changes or extensions later.

I don't have any practical knowledge about things such as Factories, dependency injections, and other such methods.
My question therefore in essence is:

**What would be the best way to ensure that the "Dice" class remains as
decoupled as possible from all other classes?**
**While still enabling them to make use of the "Dice" objects, and its methods, when needed.**

**Dice.h**

```
#ifndef dice_h_
#define dice_h_

#include <stdlib.h>

class Dice
{
  private:
    int maxValue;

  public:
    Dice(int maxValue);
    ~Dice();

    int getMaxValue( void ){return maxValue;}
    void setMaxValue(int newMaxValue){maxValue = newMaxValue;}

    int rollDice();
    int rollMultipleDice(int numberOfDiceRolls);
};
#endif
```

**Dice.cpp**

```
#ifndef dice_cpp_
#define dice_cpp_

#include "dice.h"

Dice::Dice(int maxValue){this->maxValue = maxValue;}
Dice::~Dice(){}

int Dice::rollDice()
{
  return (rand() % maxValue) + 1;
}

int Dice::rollMultipleDice(int numberOfDiceRolls)
{
  int i = numberOfDiceRolls, sum = 0;

  while(i-- > 0)
  {
    sum += rollDice();
  }

  return sum;
}
#endif
```

**Actor.h**

```
#ifndef actor_h_
#define actor_h_

#include "dice.h"

class Actor
{
  private:
    unsigned int hp;
    unsigned int ac; // Armor Class
    unsigned int dmg;
    
  public:
    Actor(unsigned int hp, unsigned int ac, unsigned int dmg);
    ~Actor();

    unsigned int getHP( void );
    unsigned int getAC( void );
    unsigned int getDmg( void );
    void setHP( unsigned int newHP);
    void setAC( unsigned int newAC);
    void setDmg( unsigned int newDmg);

    void attack(Actor* target);
    bool isHit(Actor target);
};
#endif
```

**Actor.cpp**

```
#ifndef actor_cpp_
#define actor_cpp_

#include "actor.h"

Actor::Actor(unsigned int hp, unsigned int ac, unsigned int dmg)
{
  this->hp = hp;
  this->ac = ac;
  this->dmg = dmg;
}
Actor::~Actor(){}

unsigned int Actor::getHP( void ){return hp;}
unsigned int Actor::getAC( void ){return ac;}
unsigned int Actor::getDmg( void ){return dmg;}
void Actor::setHP( unsigned int newHP ){this->hp = newHP;}
void Actor::setAC( unsigned int newAC ){this->ac = newAC;}
void Actor::setDmg( unsigned int newDmg ){this->dmg = newDmg;}

void Actor::attack(Actor* target)
{ 
  
  Dice damageDice(8);

  if (isHit(*target))
  {
    target->setHP(target->getHP() - damageDice.rollDice());
  }
}

// helper function to attack function
// do not use elsewhere
bool Actor::isHit(Actor target)
{
  Dice atkDice(20);

  return atkDice.rollDice() >= target.getAC();
}


#endif
```

Comment: your `Dice` has no dependency on `Actor`, not clear what you want to decouple

Comment: Typically, `*.cpp` files are not `#include`'d, so you don't need header guards for them.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I mean that if I instantiate Dice every time I 
need to use it (like I do in Actor::attack). Then if I change Dice later, by adding fields or changing the constructor, I would break every class or function that creates an instance of Dice.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about singletons and the like in the question so do you want ever class that needs to use the dice to use the same instance of the Dice class?

If so since the Dice class doesn't have any states to hold onto it can be a static class. I would then remove the MaxValue and add an input to the RollDice and RollMutiDice to take a Max Value (which I am guessing is suppose to the "sides" of the dice). So a call to Dice::RollDice(3) is to roll a 3 sided dice or Dice::RollMutiDice(6,3) would roll a 6 sided dice 3 times.

Also make sure you send the rand() class. I think is it srand(int). Usually you pass it time so it is fairly random

Comment: I don't want all classes to use the same instance, since they might need to use Dice with "different" number of sides.
It's an interesting idea, but would I then need the class? wouldn't it be better to simply make a set of functions then without the class?

Comment: If you can with the static methods they just need to be in a namespace somewhere that everyone can get at them. So, you could make a Dice namespace with the needed static functions instead of a class

Comment: I will definitely take a look at it, thank you so much for the help :D